# sed regular expression to do replacement for multiple cases

Tags: sed

Is it possible to have one single sed expression to do the following replacement?

```
python-lib==1.0 to python-lib>=2.0
python-lib~=1.0 to python-lib>=2.0
python-lib==1.1 to python-lib>=2.0
python-lib~=1.1 to python-lib>=2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Totally, you just need a proper regex for this. The following one should work:

```bash
sed -E 's/(python-lib)[~=]=1\.[01]/\1>=2.0/g'
```

You can try it yourself and check the explanation on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0AywaN/1).